# Why don't you have to bind a class method if you refer to it with ()?

Tags: javascript

In the React docs [page on handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), it says:

> Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as
>   onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that method.

I'm not clear on the difference between `onClick={this.handleClick}` and `onClick={this.handleClick()}` or why using the `()` means you wouldn't need to bind `this`.

Any help in understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `()` mean that you want to immediately *call* the function and use whatever value it returns.

Comment: Never use `onClick={this.handleClick()}`. It won't work (whether it binds `this` or not). Either use `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}` or `onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}`. To be clear: the advice from the docs does not suggest that you can use `this.handleClick()` nor that you don't have to bind `this` if you do that. Again, `onClick={this.handleClick()}` is always bad.

Comment: I'm still confused because it seems like it's also called without the `()` (as long as `this` is bound). In an example on the Handling Events page I linked, `{this.handleClick}` seems to call the `handleClick()` method defined on the class. I don't see `handleClick()` anywhere.

Comment: This isn't specific to React, and doesn't really have anything to do with binding. Here's a plain JS example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/23nmurt4/

Comment: `I don't see handleClick() anywhere.` You assigned `this.handleClick` to `onClick`, so when React calls `element.onClick()`, that's when `this.handleClick()` gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When affecting a function reference to a new variable, the context (refered by `this` inside that function) is not copied.

In the snippet below, the saysHi function uses `this`. The object it references changes depending on the way it's called or bound.

```js
const jack = {
  name : 'Jack',
  saysHi : function() {
    console.log("Hi, I'm " + this.name);  
  }
};
jack.saysHi(); // this will reference jack

const someoneSaysHi = jack.saysHi;
someoneSaysHi(); // this will not reference jack anymore, but the global object window

const joe = { name : "Joe" };
const joeSaysHi = someoneSaysHi.bind(joe);
joeSaysHi(); // this will reference joe, because you bound the function to joe
```

- By calling `jack.saysHi()`, this will be a reference to `jack`. I'm calling the function with the . operator, invoking it in the context of the `jack` object.
- By setting `const someoneSaysHi = jack.saysHi ;` and then calling `someoneSaysHi ()`, I'm calling it without any context. So `this` will be a reference to the global object `window`. That's a feature of the language.
- By binding `someoneSaysHi` to the joe context, I'm creating a new function and in that function, the this will be a reference to `joe`.

More complete answer : [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Now, about about your issue :

> Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as
>   onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that method.

The onClick attribute needs a function reference to attach to the click event.

- `onClick={this.handleClick()}` will immediatly call `this.handleClick` (with the right context) and attach the click event to the returned value of the `this.handleClick` function.
- `onClick={this.handleClick}` without binding anything will attach the the click event to the `handleClick` function, but in that context, the `this` inside your `handleClick` function will be the event's current target (the element you clicked on) - this is a feature of event handlers.
- `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}` will attach the click event to a new function reference bound to the object referenced by `this`.

Answer (score 3):

`this.handleClick` refers to a function. `this.handleClick()` calls that function.

It's not so much that using `()` removes the need for binding, it's just that in the context of calling `this.handleClick()` javacript "knows" what `this` should refer to.

So if I call:

```
this.handleClick();
```

It's clear from context what `this` was.

But if I call

```
const foo = this.handleClick;
foo();
```

I'm still calling the same function, but the original reference to `this` was gone.

As for 'why' that is. I don't know the historical reason for this, but it a side-effect of how Javascript was defined. The javascript language would probably be a little nicer if this was not the case, but this is how the language works. I'm not sure if this is a satisfying answer.